# Run Nodejs App Every 6 Hours with Aysnc Await

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to run a Script every 6 Hours

```
const { IgApiClient } = require("instagram-private-api")
const ig = new IgApiClient()

const USERNAME = "abc"
const PASSWORD = "xyz"

ig.state.generateDevice(USERNAME)
const main = async () => {
    var birthday = new Date(2069, 05, 14);
    var today = new Date();
    birthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());
    if (today > birthday) {
    birthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);
    }
    var daystill = Math.floor((birthday - today) / (1000*60*60*24))

    await ig.simulate.preLoginFlow()
    await ig.account.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    process.nextTick(async () => await ig.simulate.postLoginFlow())
    await ig.account.setBiography(`${daystill} Days till my Birthday, Today is ${new Date().getDate()}/${new Date().getMonth()}/${new Date().getFullYear()}. (AutoGenerated)`)
}
main()
```

[instagram-private-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api)
**About Script:** update my Instagram Bio with Async Await
**Problem / Goal:**
I Tried using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), but It returns some Error (I think `Async` is causing the Problem), I also tried while loops and `setInterval()`s
I want this Script/File to run every 6 Hours, I have a heroku account (if that helps)

**Error when i use node-cron:**

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

**Code for node-cron:**

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => { // this is not every 6hrs
    const main = async () => {
       //same as above
    }
    
    main()
})
```

Comment: "I Tried using node-cron," — Not in the code you've shared with us you haven't. "It returns some Error" — Which says what? "I think Async is causing the Problem" — Why do you think that?

Comment: wait, lemme edit the question real quick

Comment: I'd expect the message associated with that uncaught exception to be logged somewhere.

Comment: I added the code when i used `node-cron`

Comment: But not the details of the exception that was thrown.

Comment: here is the entire console : https://database.jaazim.tech/stackoverflow-error.png

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the async await way as the title says.

```js
// used to measure time
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';

const interval = 1000; // in ms

(async function main(){
    let start_time = performance.now();

    // do stuff

    let stop_time = performance.now();

    let timeout = interval - (stop_time - start_time);
    setTimeout(main, timeout);
})();
```

edit:
To explain the syntax behind the main function.
`()();` will automatically call the function inside of first braces on script start.

Comment: Thanks for Your Contribution, but, I still get the Same error (https://database.jaazim.tech/stackoverflow-error.png)

Comment: Maybe theres something wrong with my code :(

Comment: Its telling you that the account was not found.

Comment: No, i tried with the Same credentials, it worked

Comment: You will find [more info here](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1271). I would open up another question with your specific problem.